# Ionic time select fails to display AM / PM for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Works for iOS, but fails in Android with replacing AM / PM with ..

Here's the code that works for iOS

```
<ion-datetime  #datePicker
        text-center
        (ionChange)="dateChanged($event)"
  displayFormat="hh:mm A" 
  minuteValues="0,10,20,30,40,50"
  [(ngModel)]="time"
  (ionCancel)="navCtrl.pop()"
  >
```

on iOS the above code allows the user to scroll through and select either AM / PM

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because your picker-option it is to small, you resolve this by putting

```
.picker-opts { max-width: 70px !important; }
```

in your app.scss 
hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this asap.

Comment: let me know if it help, I had a rough time with this problem. If you are using ionic 4 you have to put it in your global.scss

Comment: Yup, that solved it. I put it to `90px` and it now shows.

Comment: In Ionic4 you have to place the CSS into the global.scss file